# Angularjs custom directive cannot work for ui-sref

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ui-sref

First, this works: `<a ui-sref="students({courseId: $ctrl.Course.Id})">{{ student.Name }}</a>`
Which supports that my router works fine.

I create a custom directive: **link: "=link"**

```
<div ng-if="$ctrl.link && $ctrl.link.Name && $ctrl.link.State">
            <a ui-sref="{{$ctrl.link.State}}">{{$ctrl.link.Name}}</a>
</div>
```

Why this cannot work:

```
<div link="{ Name: 'View Students', State: 'students({courseId: $ctrl.Course.Id})' }">
```

Here is the error:

> Transition Rejection($id: 0 type: 6, message: The transition errored, detail: Error: Param values not valid for state ‘students’)

Update:
My custom directive

```
angular.module('Foo').component('Bar', {
        controller: LinkController,
        templateUrl: "link.tpl.html",
        transclude: true,
        bindings: {
            link: "=link",
    });
```

Comment: Please post the definition of your directive.

Comment: I added my directive definition.

Comment: the error narrows it down a little. your `({courseId: $ctrl.Course.Id})` is not being evaluated correctly. also it looks like you have a floating single quote after that last parentheses.

Comment: It was just my typo. I added another single quote to it.

Comment: Is this `{courseId: $ctrl.Course.Id}` evaluated as a result of a promise? If it is , there is no way for your directive to know whether the promise is fulfilled or rejected.

Comment: "Is this {courseId: $ctrl.Course.Id} evaluated as a result of a promise?" Yes.  "If it is , there is no way for your directive to know whether the promise is fulfilled or rejected." Any solution for it if I still want this custom directive.

Comment: it kind of seems like overkill to create a component/directive just to hold a link. you can do it easily without the directive `<a ui-sref="students({ courseId: $ctrl.Course.courseId })">View Students</a>`. If you want to keep the directive then just put a `ng-click` on the anchor tag and call `$state.go()` in your LinkController

Comment: I have other properties for my custom directive, I just list the 'link' for simplicity here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem as below:

**How I debug**: I try to replace ‘$ctrl.Course.Id’ with 123 (Number), it works. So I know my custom link directive is working.

```
<div link="{ Name: 'View Students', State: 'students({courseId: $ctrl.Course.Id})' }">
```

Then I realized that it is because I put this ‘$ctrl.Course.Id’ inside the single quote, it will parse it as a string, instead of a number.

**So, this is what I did:**

Go to component, make an object:
`this.studentsLink = { Name: 'View Students', State: 'students({courseId:'.concat(this.$stateParams.courseId, '})')};`

My *this.$stateParams.courseId* is a string. If it is a number, we should do `this.$stateParams.courseId.toString()`

Then go to Template:

```
<div link="$ctrl.studentsLink">
```

Hope this help future developers who have the same problem.